# How To Run Discord bot inside Django and use signals with it

Tags: django, discord.py, django-signals

So I have created my django website and. I want to **run my discord bot inside my django website**
And also **can I use the signals to send a message on my server if post have been crated **
So any one can help me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really hard to run both a discord bot and a Django website in a single script. I wouldn't recommend it.

The easiest approach would be using the [discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) and making requests to it.

However, if you still want to use specifically `discord.py` you can use webhooks: 
Firstly create a webhook:

> Go to Server Settings > Integrations > Webhooks > Create Webhook

And copy the webhook URL

```py
import requests  # pip install requests
from discord import SyncWebhook

webhook_url = "your webhook URL"
session = requests.Session()

webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url(webhook_url, session=session)

# To send a message
webhook.send("New post has been created")
```

Comment: Thanks man you solved my problem I actually didn't know about webhooks 